# CakePHP 3 Between two date

Tags: orm, cakephp-3.0, between

I try to do an query in my controller, I want find all entity where the start and en date are between NOW(),
if $start and $end are between NOW() so show all entity, but i didn't succeed

My find is :

```
$day = date('l');
$now = Time::now();
$tvs = $this->Tvs
         ->find('all')
         ->contain(['Users'])
         ->where(['Tvs.day' => $day])
         ->andWhere(function($exp) {
               return $exp->between($now, 'Tvs.start', 'tvs.end', $now);
                          });
```

How make this query ?
Thanks for you'r help !

Comment: you mean: `$now` is between `start` and `end`, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to find all twhe record having `$now` between `start` and `end` the query is

sice the manual says that the first argument of the between fucntion should be name of the field (so it can't be a date) instead of between you can use two comparison

```
$tvs = $this->Tvs
    ->find('all')
    ->contain(['Users'])
    ->where(['Tvs.day' => $day])
    ->andWhere(function($exp) use($now) {
        $exp->lte('Tvs.start', $now);
        $exp->gte('Tvs.end', $now);
        return $exp;
     });
```

anyway you can make use of the mysql NOW() function directly into the query if the $now variable contains the same value of the NOW() function

```
->andWhere(function($exp, $q) {
     return $exp->between($q->func()->now(), 'Tvs.start', 'Tvs.end');
});
```

there's anothe method: you can use BETWEEN and a palceholder to bind the value of $now

```
 ->andWhere([':now BETWEEN Tvs.start AND Tvs.end'])
 ->bind(':now', $now, 'datetime');
```

or using cakephp sql functions

```
->where(function($exp, $q) {
    return $exp->between(':now', 'Tvs.start', 'Tvs.end');
})
->bind(':now', $now, 'datetime');
```

Comment: Yeah, this function is correct, but my $now is Time::now(); and i have an error SQL --> use near '09:34, i think the between don't take the date format Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: I looked into the between() documentation. See my edit

Comment: Thanks for your help, i read the documentation and i understand the query builder, it's work !

Comment: I've added a third solution

Answer (score 0):

Since CakePHP 3.6 you can use identifiers:

```
return $query->where(function ($exp, $q) {
    
    $today = $q->func()->now();
    $start = $q->identifier('Tvs.start');
    $end   = $q->identifier('Tvs.end');
    
    return $exp
        ->between($today,$start,$end);
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution. However, if your MySQL database is stored on a different server OR it has a different time zone configured then you need to consider other solutions.